# Powershell interop with C#, pass by reference possible?

Tags: c#, powershell, delegates, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to get a Powershell delegate to successfully alter a pass-by-reference argument when invoked from a C# class. I'm a Powershell guy more than I'm C#, you see :)

The following code and output summarises the problem I'm having:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

$csharp_code = @'
namespace BingleBongle
{
    public class Giblets
    {
        public delegate int DSomeFunc(ref bool Cancel);

        public static bool WutWut(
            DSomeFunc someFunc
            )
        {
            bool Cancel = false;
            int result = someFunc(ref Cancel);

            if (Cancel == false &&
                result == 69)
            {
                Cancel = true;
            }

            return Cancel;
        }
    }
}
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $csharp_code

'anon function' | Out-Host

[BingleBongle.Giblets]::WutWut([BingleBongle.Giblets+DSomeFunc]{
    param ([ref] $Cancel)
    $Cancel.Value | Out-Host
    $Cancel.Value = [bool]$true
    $Cancel.Value | Out-Host
})

'variable' | Out-Host

$myDelegate = [BingleBongle.Giblets+DSomeFunc]{
    param ([ref] $Cancel)
    $Cancel.Value | Out-Host
    $Cancel.Value = [bool]$true
    $Cancel.Value | Out-Host

    69
}

[BingleBongle.Giblets]::WutWut($myDelegate)
```

In both cases altering $Cancel.Value has no effect, and does not alter Cancel in the C# class.

The second attempt cheeses things by returning a value (69) to the C# class to indicate we should change Cancel. It's a workaround but using it would mean altering the real code, and I'd much rather get pass-by-ref working if possible. Of course it might not be supported!

Here's the output of the above:

```
anon function
False
True
False
variable
False
True
True
```

Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: You should be using fixed, to get around the GC moving the list around in memory while something unmanaged is working on it with naked pointers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement | That is where my knowledge of Interop and Unsafe code ends. I really prefer never to use Call by reference in that context.

Comment: Indeed just to be really sure, my "call Powershell" C# function would also: 1. Get the Argument by ref. 2. Createa a clone to hand it to the Powershell. 3. Then assign the modified clone back to the argument, after Powershell is done.

Comment: Wouldnt it make more sense to build a binary library?

Comment: For background, the real script is entirely PS, except that because PS cannot cast COM objects (as other COM objects), you have to dip into C# to cast WebBrowser as SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2. This exposes BeforeNavigate2, which has a Cancel arg, passed by ref. My script wants to set Cancel to true to cancel a navigation, but as the example above shows, it doesn't seem to work. The BeforeNavigate2 handler is a Powershell function.